# Rails data modeling question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, models

I am creating a simple todo app where I have 2 types of tasks.

1) regular tasks - These have a due date
2) recurring tasks -These are poped up as reminders on specified date. They can be created either as weekly or monthly reminders. If created for a week, it will be poped up on each week (on a specified date on the week). Likewise for a month it need to be specified the week and the date.

What will be the best way to model this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I would have two columns for the reminder object - `remind_at` (date) and `repeat_frequency` (something to identify different re-occurrences by). That way, you could index the `remind_at` column and search by it quite quickly. Each time a reminder is shown to user, it would look at `repeat_frequency` - if it contains directions for repeating, set `remind_at` to next date, if not, delete/archive the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You could model a `Task` to have a `due_date`. But if a task is recurring, `due_date` will be null and you would use the `recurrence` field to compute the `next_due_date`. `recurrence` would be a string field holding a parsable string like "tuesday" (for weekly) or "17" (a day number for monthly).

```
def next_due_date
  if due_date
    due_date
  else
    # compute next due date using the 'recurrence' field and today's date
  end
end
```

This may or may not be the "best way" for you, depending on your requirements, and the future needs of the model.